# Set method name for MetaMask history

Tags: web3js, metamask

I have a question about the Metamask UI.

Is it possible to set custom transaction method name for metamask history to make it more user-friendly? I want to rename "Bid" (default method name) to "Made bids for cake". I can't find any docs about it, anyone knows how does it works?

[image: Transaction method name screenshot]

**UPDATED**

I've tried to test new contract with a few different functions,
all of them named as **"Unknown function"** inside Metamask ext UI history (when I expected to see **"Set Test Value"**). Even for `set` function its unknown result.

How should I name function for Metamask UI correctly?

```
contract NamingTest {
    uint256 test;

    function set_test_value(uint256 _value) external payable {
        test = _value;
    }

    function setTestValue(uint256 _value) external payable {
        test = _value;
    }

    function settestvalue(uint256 _value) external payable {
        test = _value;
    }

    function set(uint256 _value) external payable {
        test = _value;
    }

    function getTest() external view returns (uint256) {
        return test;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, as the Metamask UI pulls that name directly from the contract. Your only solution, for now, is to create a contract with a different function name.

If this is not your contract, then you cannot change this name on the Metamask UI.

Comment: I was hoping there was a way :) I've updated my first post with the Contract test, now I don't understand how should I name functions correctly for the MetaMask, all of it shows as Unknown function. Maybe I wrong with the code?